# what is the new command for sudo nautilus on ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: command-line, unity

I'm on ubuntu kinetic kudu 22.10 unity and I want to know what command now replaces the old command ''nautilus''.

Comment: Avoid using "sudo" for graphical apps altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The command you mention in the title *never* has been a valid command. It has been a recipe to potentially break your system.

To perform file management as root user, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then type "admin://" to open the root directory with administrator privileges.

To directly move into a specific directory, add the path, e.g. "admin:///etc".

To launch a new window (i.e., this actually answers your specific question):

```
nautilus admin://
```

Proceed the same for system file editing with the graphical file manager, e.g. `gedit admin:///etc/fstab` or provide the "admin://" URI in the file open dialog.